# How to enable search box in the SharePoint top ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, modern-team-site

In my other tenant, I could see the search box at the top of each site (SharePoint top ribbon), but in my below-mentioned tenant I am missing that - I have checked but didn't find any configuration for that.

[image: How to enable searchbox in the ribbon]

Can anyone please help me to enable this search box in the SharePoint top ribbon.

Comment: I would suggest asking the separate question for the search result page redirection issue,

Comment: @LittSpector - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding enable the search bar:**

Check the Release preferences setting in the admin center of your tenants.

Your other tenant must be set to get the Targeted release under which you get all the latest changes that are not yet ruled out for all the users.

Your current tenant might be set to Standart Release (By Default). So it will not have the latest changes which are not ruled out for everyone.

However, you can get all the latest changes on your current tenant only for the selected user by setting the Release preferences to Targeted release for the select users.

Reference: [Set up the release option in the admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide#set-up-the-release-option-in-the-admin-center)

You can do the same using PnP PowerShell as well. Below is an example.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/[site]" -UseWebLogin
try{
 $web = Get-PnPWeb
 #0 - Inherit, #1 - AllPages, #2 - ModernOnly, #3 - Hidden enums for Global (Modern Search)
 $web.SearchBoxInNavBar=2
 $web.Update()
 Invoke-PnPQuery
 Write-Host "Done" -BackgroundColor Green   
}
catch{
 Write-Host "No permission" -BackgroundColor Red    
}
Write-Host "All Done"
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood you correctly. :-) I have executed the above PnP but still, I didn't get the search box at the top.

Comment: Did you checked the first approach from Admin center?

Comment: make sure your release preference is set to Targeted Release

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As per the Microsoft 365 Roadmap for [Microsoft Search GA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/roadmap?ms.url=roadmap&rtc=1&filters=&searchterms=34273),  the feature is **Rolling out** for O365 Standard Release and the estimated time frame is Q1 CY2020.

Currently it is not supported to manually enable this feature in Office365 tenant. I suggest you wait for the status gets updated to **Launched** in the Microsoft 365 Roadmap site so that you can get this feature automatically.

Change the [Release preferences](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/Settings/OrganizationProfile/:/Settings/L1/ReleasePreferences) for your tenant to **Targeted release for everyone** or **Targeted release for select users** if necessary. It can take up to 24 hours for the changes to take effect in Office 365.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked with the Targeted release setting changes and the above PnP command provided by Litt Spector