# In modern SharePoint online, search result page is not redirecting to custom result page

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience

I have created a custom search result page "**results.aspx**"  and configured in the search setting page as below:

[image: Custom Result Page configuration in search settings]

However, when I search for something in the site it takes me to the below default search result page

https://globalsharepoint2020.sharepoint.com/**_layouts/15/search.aspx**/siteall?q=Test

As per the configuration, it should take me to the below custom page.

https://globalsharepoint2020.sharepoint.com/sites/CustomSearchRND/**SitePages/Results.aspx**

I have followed the same steps in my other tenant where it works as expected but it is not working here. Am I missing any configuration steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of the above issue, sharing the solution with the community.

In order to get it working first, we should enable the search box at the top ribbon mentioned below.

[image: How to enable searchbox in the ribbon]

**Solution:**

Enable the search box at the top ribbon, using the below SSE post:

[How to enable search box in the SharePoint top ribbon?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278854/how-to-enable-search-box-in-the-sharepoint-top-ribbon)

Then, automatically it redirects to the custom result page as expected.